# Wiring Lilypad USB + ESP8266 Serial WiFi Module

Tags: wifi, wires, esp8266

I am trying to solve the following scenario:
Lilypad USB connected to WIFI through ESP8266 Serial WiFi Module.

http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Main/ArduinoBoardLilyPadUSB

http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/WiFi_Serial_Transceiver_Module

According to the wiki:
I should connect to TX RX pins. None of them are present as "selectable pins", because they are built in.

This post [Using LilyPad Arduino USB with LilyPad Xbee Shield](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=245169.0)  talks about using SoftwareSerial something that is new to me.

Could anyone explain how should I proceed with the wiring and if possible a sample sketch just to connect the lilypad usb with the WIFI module to my personal WIFI.

**Edit:**

I found the following [tutorial](http://www.prometec.net/arduino-wifi/) (spanish one but easy to follow...) where they use the Arduino UNO. I tried the example with the software serial and it worked. 
I saw in that tutorial sometimes the pin RST is needed. So I tried to do the same with the lilypad USB, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, upload the sketch below to your Arduino. Then, try to tie RX (pin 3) and TX (pin 2) of SoftwareSerial together. Open the Serial Monitor and send some text and see if you get it back as a response.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(3, 2);

void setup()
  {  Serial.begin(9600);
     Serial1.begin(9600);
  }

void loop()
  {
     if (Serial1.available())
         { char c = Serial1.read() ;
           Serial.print(c);
         }
     if (Serial.available())
         {  char c = Serial.read();
            Serial1.print(c);
         }
   }
```

Once you get a response, then your SoftwareSerial part is working and you can then try to connect to your ESP8266.